# Cannot find correct path to image in Angular - Node app

Tags: node.js, angular, image

I am having trouble displaying an image which is in my angular folder app.
here is my folder structure:
[image]

I am accessing it from the contact.component folder; I have tried accessing directly like src="../images/DNS.jpg" and relatively to the index.html file src="./app/images/DNS.jpg" and it doesn't work.
How can I reference this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all your images in assets folder and Try this :

```
<img src="assets/DNS.jpg" />
```

As, angular recommends to put all your resources in the assets folder including images/fonts etc and access from there.

Comment: Yep it recognises it in the assests folder. Tanks